# PHP mail() function not working

Tags: 12.04, php, postfix, sendmail

I've been trying to configure the mail() function for 3 days by now, and I'm running out of ideas.
I've installed and configured postfix as a satellite, following this guide: [How to have my PHP Send mail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail) but it seems I lack the file /etc/postfix/sender_canonical (and of course I have no idea of what to put inside it). By now this is the only clue I have about the problem... 
I'm trying to run it on Ubuntu 12.04 laptop, built with x32 architecture.

**EDIT:** After a few iterations of apt-get purge and apt-get install, mail() started to return true, the error log has stopped growing so it seems all ok, but no mail managed to reach my inbox, not even as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be overkill for what you want,  but following the directions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

and literally just copy pasting all commands and following the directions carefully should get you there.

I run 12.04 on three different systems and have set all of them up this way - i've had zero problems with mail().

I'm still a bit of a newbie at this, so like i said - it might be overkill for what you need.  Hope it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

Check php config file and try to use simple sendmail instead of postfix.

Comment: I tried it in attempts 2-5, but thank you