# I can send mails from shell with PHP, but I can't send from the PHP web page

Tags: server, php, email

I'm trying to send mails from a contact form in a page on my server.

I followed this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/368046).

My PHP file /var/www/my_project/test.php is this:

```
<?php
$myemail = "my_mail@gmail.com";
$subject = "my subject";
$message = "my message ";
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
echo "sent";
?>
```

If I run the PHP file from the shell:

```
php /var/www/my_project/test.php
```

I receive the email in Gmail, then, I'm supposing *ssmtp* is well configured, right?

But if I run the PHP from the browser:

```
http://localhost/my_project/test.php
```

it doesn't send the mail and it creates this file with the email content:

```
/var/www/dead.letter
```

I did these steps too:

```
costales@server:~$ sudo cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep sendmail
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
costales@server:~$ sudo service apache2 reload

costales@server:~$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 173.194.67.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP dm2sm7052263wib.8 - gsmtp
```

Any idea please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it Drupal? Then you might take a look at this post: https://drupal.org/comment/2032080#comment-2032080

It might have to do with user permissions. Try adding the apache user to `/etc/mail/virtusertable` and rehashing the `/etc/mail/virtusertable.db`

Sendmail needs to be configured for it to work with the httpd server user.

Comment: No, It's just a PHP page :) It's this: http://html5templatesdreamweaver.com/bootstrap-form.html