# Send an email from the localserver using PHP

Tags: server, php, thunderbird, email, postfix

I am trying to send an email to my thunderbird or google acount using PHP from a local server in Ubuntu. I have used the mail() function in PHP.

I have done some research and apparently you can not send an email from the local server unless you install an email system. So I went with postfix and installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

For the configuration I chose Satellite.
I don't know how to proceed from here.

What should I type for **System mail name**, is localhost correct?

I left SMTP relay host and Root and postmaster mail recipient:  blank.

I am very much confused and could not find any step by step tutorial. I would appreciate any help and some clarification on how to finish the steps in postfix configuration.

Edit: I looked at this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

But why **System mail name: example.com** and why we choose **General type of mail configuration: Internet Site**?

Comment: because localhost is not recognisable on the internet as it is local name; as for Internet Site - that is standard configuration for standalone machine that wants to communicate with the outside

Comment: This can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail

Answer (score 0):

In short: choose **Internet Site** as a configuration and use fqdn for Mail System name (if you use localhost it will be classified as spam most likely).

Problem is, for some of the mail servers nowadays it will not be enough (for example, gmail tends to classify such configuration as spam).

What else will you need:

- MX DNS record (a DNS record, that will point to appropriate IP as a Mail target for given domain - you can check it with `host -t MX domain`)
- `postconf -e "myhostname = [hosts fqdn]"`
- `postconf -e "myorigin = \$myhostname"`

Comment: You can do much more in term of configuration, but I've found out that that was the bare minimum for my LAMP stack to send mail via mail() correctly.

Comment: Thanks, would it work for both gmail and thunderbird?

Comment: What do you mean - gmail is a mail service, thunderbird is just email client. Thunderbird will work with any IMAP service. If you will see emails in gmail interface, then Thunderbird will work :)

Comment: The thing is I get an email as www-data@example.com in my gmail account using mail() function of php but when I change the email address to my company's email address which is set-up using windowslivemail (I get my emails through thunderbird in ubuntu) I don't see anything.

Comment: Yeap, totally correct - you don't want to anybody be able to spoof author like this. So generally most mail servers won't allow an email originating from one domain if from header disagrees. BUT, you can configure your postfix as a relay and tell it to authenticate with your work email which will have effect of emails seem to be originating from your work email.

Comment: I have typed      postconf -e "myhostname = [hosts fqdn]"
and     postconf -e "myorigin = \$myhostname"   ...and now I can not even get an email in my gmail :(

Comment: ANy idea of how to undo this?

Comment: hmmm ... you did substitute `[hosts fqdn]` with proper fqdn, right? can you paste the contents of /etc/postfix/main.cf ?

Comment: no I have just copy pasted it, what is the proper fqdn?

Comment: mtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = [hosts fqdn]
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost, example.comserver1.example.com, example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname

Comment: I guess fqdn is the hostname of my computer right?

Comment: got it I have typed hostname --fqdn I am am going to change it now

Comment: FQDN is Fully Qualified Domain Name (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) - in simple terms [hostname].[domainname], for example: mail.domain.com. It doesn't have to be your machine name, but it has to be the name where MX records for your domain point. And it should be added to /etc/hosts as well (to the line with your external IP, not 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1)

Comment: just don't change it to localhost :)

Comment: also, `mydestination` should contain your domain and probably NOT contain the stuff with *example.com (unless you own example.com :))

Comment: ok thanks I will fix them and will let you know if it works out!

Comment: Still not working. I

Comment: smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = [mary]
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, mary, localhost.localdomain, localhost, radar.com
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
myorigin = $mary

Comment: For my destination should I put the part before .com of my windowslive work email?

Comment: Maybe I should download dovecot