# mail() / sendmail not working on lubuntu 14.04 in virtualbox guest

Tags: email, postfix, mail, sendmail

I tried:

`postfix`

`ssmtp`

from this post [How to have my PHP Send mail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail)

and the classical

`sendmail`

with `sudo sendmailconfig`

nothing works

I can see no error messages.

My host is windows 10.

Any ideas?

I tried as well:

`echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@gmail.com`

and

`echo "test"|mail -s test mymail@gmail.com`

no errors in neither

no spam email, nothing

`phpinfo()` shows

`sendmail_path  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

Answer (score 0):

i actually made it work using `ssmtp` from the link in the question and turning on https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

using a gmail address