# How to schedule emails with varying content?

Tags: thunderbird, schedule

I recently moved to Ubuntu 14.04 and encounter my first problems. I would like to create a schedule for automatic email transmission.
I'm running some queries every morning via `cron` which are saved as report  `query.pdf` in one specific path.

I would like to send an email afterwards to a specific group of recipients using the preinstalled Thunderbird client. I have already found `Send later`. However, it doesn't attach the`query.pdf` when the content changes every morning.

Is there another way or add-on? I just couldn't find anything at all.

Comment: Is scheduling a task with `cron` an option? E.g. "send a mail X every day at 15.00 PM". Or in other words, is this task to be scheduled at regular time intervals and can we rely on the fact that the system will be up at a certain X time to perform it?

Comment: I do schedule tasks with `cron`. At 08.45 I run `R-Script`which generates via `knitr` and `LaTeX` a PDF in a specific folder/path. The PDF contains daily Google Analytics Report. I just want to attach that PDF automatically. `Send Later`seems to be a good tool but its doesnt attach PDFs each morning. Its just attach the PDF you have chosen beforehand.

Comment: Yes, the system is always running.

Comment: How about just chaining a command to send the mail right at the end of the command you already have in the cron job? That should work unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe you want suggest a solution or an example? I' running:`45 08 * * * sudo Rscript /home/me/ga.R` which trigges a `LaTex` file running for 3min and saving the PDF afterwards as `query.pdf` in `/home/me/pdfs/query.pdf`

Comment: all you need is another cronjob to send email immediately after the genration of pdf file. So I see your cron job is running at 08:45 you can use mutt (mutt -s "email subject" -a /home/me/pdfs/query.pdf group@domain.com < /tmp/mail.txt) where mail.txt is the body of email that contains text. So you can put all that in cronjob that will run, say at 08:50 and that will do

Comment: So I have to use Mutt (or msmtp  as well?) rather then Thunderbird for that specific purpose?

Comment: I agree with @ostendali. Related: [How to send mail from the command line?](/q/12917/175814); `mpack` in combination with `ssmtp` looks promising for your purpose.

Comment: Is this possible: Telling thunderbird to attach a file. Then, when you generate the file, rename it to the named file. Or, setup a link to that file with the latest generated file in your cron job. Does it work?

Comment: Thank you for all suggestios. May I use `mutt`with microsoft exchange server?

Comment: Hah!  Now the cat comes out of the box: Microsoft Exchange server???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to install an [SMTP send connector](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997285%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) on your Microsoft Exchange server and then it's just a question of:

- [configuring sendmail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail)
- adding the following line to your cron script:

  ```
  mutt -s "query report" -a /home/me/pdfs/query.pdf me-group@HiThere.com < /home/me/mail/query-report-body.txt
  ```

  where:

  - `-s subject` is the subject of the message. (`query report` in the example above)
  - `-a file` is the attached report file to your message. (example taken from your comment)
  - `me-group@HiThere.com` is the SMTP address of the Exchange group you're sending the mail to.
  - `query-report-body.txt` is the text file containing the body message of your report.

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**